# Flat Tax vs. National Income Tax Average

Tags: education, economics, average, percentages, word-problem

If the national income tax average under a progressive system is 30%, will tax revenue change if the progressive system is changed to a flat tax also at 30%?

In other words, if the mean average person in the US pays 30% of his/her income for taxes, will a flat tax at 30% change the overall tax revenue that the federal government receives?

Comment: +1) Yes absolutely, because using the mean is a flawed statistic for this purpose. The problem is that very often the Median average person will not be at the 30% rate. Don't be surprised that the Median is lower than the Mean when it comes to income distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So how could we go about implementing a flat tax system so that the overall tax revenue is not changed?

Comment: You'd need to take the total tax revenue and divide by the number of "entities" (individuals, couples) paying tax.

Comment: In addition to pjs36 answer: You need some more data, because changing the income tax system also often changes the tax-bylaws of the country. It's more complicated as you can see

Comment: A small example: Suppose the function for the taxes, which have to be payed is $f(x)=0.001x^2$. You have 3 tax payers with an income of 100,120 and 150. Then the taxes are $10,14.4$ and $22.5$ The sum is 46.9. And the ratio of payed taxes and incomes is $\frac{46.9}{100+120+150}\approx 12.68\%$. With this flat tax rate the goverment would get the equal amount of taxes. But this is a pure **mathematical consideration**. Firstly, the tax laws are much more complicated (e.g.. tax exemption). Secondly, this kind of change in taxing will influence the economy very much.

Comment: Consider migrating this question to economics.stackexchange.com .